# heading rows with different n by group in R

Tags: r, purrr

I'm trying to get the first n parts of an object, but with different n per group, according values I have in other object.

I have the next replicable example:

```
a<- tibble(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 
           group = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2))
b<- tibble(group=c(1,2), 
           n = c(3,4))
```

where what I want is to get the first 3 rows of a when the group is 1, and the first 4 rows of a when the group is 2.

I've trying doing this:

```
  cob<- a %>%  group_by(group) %>% arrange(id, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  group_map(~head(.x, b$n))
```

But I just get the first 3 rows in both groups, and not different size for each group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a join and then `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% 
  left_join(b) %>% 
   group_by(group) %>% 
   filter(row_number() <= first(n)) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-n)
```

---

or another option is

```
a %>% 
   group_by(group) %>% 
   slice(seq_len(b$n[match(cur_group(), b$group)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a data.table solution.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a)    # only needed because you started with a tibble
setDT(b)    # same
a[b, on=.(group)][, .(id=id[1:n]), by=.(group, n)]

   group n V1
1:     1 3  1
2:     1 3  2
3:     1 3  3
4:     2 4  6
5:     2 4  7
6:     2 4  8
7:     2 4  9
```

The first clause: `a[b, on=.(group)]` joins `b` to `a` creating a data.table with columns `group`, `id`, and `n`. The second clause: `[, .(id=id[1:n]), by=.(group, n)]` groups by `group`, taking the first `n` elements of `id` in each group.